# Container type and compile-time type deduction

Tags: c++, templates, stl, compile-time, type-deduction

I want to have a vector of integers and some code, that processes that vector in a most general way (at compile-time) w.r.t. the vector element type. E.g.:

```
std::vector<uint16_t> X;
...
X.push_back(rand() % std::numeric_limits<X::value_type>::max());
```

But the compiler says:

```
the value of X is not usable in a constant expression
```

Why cannot `X::value_type` be used in such a context? I mean `X`'s element type cannot change once it is declared with concrete element type, and this can be deduced from syntax of this piece of code alone.
And what should be the approach if I change the declared `X`'s element type (another integer), but do not want to change the `push_back` string due to that change? I am assuming any modern C++ standard.

Comment: Generalization is good. Though not if its for the sake of generalization alone. If what you show is indeed in one scope, there really is no need to contort your code like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`X` is the name of the object, not the type. You can use [`decltype`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/decltype) (since C++11) to get the type of `X`.

```
X.push_back(rand() % std::numeric_limits<decltype(X)::value_type>::max());
```

Comment: @orlp It yields `uint16_t&`, not just `uint16_t`.

Comment: I thought `numeric_limits` would decay that but I guess I'm wrong.

Comment: @orlp Yes it doesn't; `std::remove_reference` has to be used to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

If you change it to call `value_type` on a type (instead of an instance - I don't think that's a valid `C++`) it will compile and work ([godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/AIWmVh)).

```
using vec_t = std::vector<uint16_t>;
vec_t X;
// or the other way around:
// auto X = std::vector<uint16_t>();
// using vec_t = decltype(X);
X.push_back(rand() % std::numeric_limits<vec_t::value_type>::max());
```